# Seraphin song lyrics help

Tags: song-lyrics

I have been listening a song in Latin called seraphin and was wondering if anyone could get me the Latin lyrics so I can finally know what they are saying in the song.
the link to the song is https://youtu.be/a32JN3PIN-c and I would be ever so grateful if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 3):

One of the fans wrote this down

> timebam me te invenire
>   oculis tuis me perlegentem
>   et quid viri sim
>   timebam me de te perire amore
>
> eum primum

I can add that the  second verse is a repeat. That the third verse contains the word *semper,* (always). It means, roughly,

"I was afraid that I would find you  reading me  thoroughly with your eyes, and what sort of man I am. I was afraid to die from love of you."